# Has anyone been able to replicate Yarn's (package manager) claimed performance?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I had lunch last week with a friend who professed how awesome yarn is and how its much faster than npm. Being someone who spends far too much time watching npm progress bars I just run a comparison using a project I already had.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/compare

In all cases i've removed the node_modules folder first. I figured yarn would need a chance to cache so my first run `yarn install` took about 7m 10s. The second run (and i did see the fetching take almost no time) took 5m 20s.

Jumping back to npm which already has these dependencies cachef it took almost exactly two minutes to run `npm install`. So my results are the complete opposite of yarn's own compare page.

Is there something deeply flawed about how I've compared these?

Here are the dependencies installed in my test:

```
"angular": "^1.5.8",
"angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
"angular-i18n": "^1.5.8",
"angular-moment": "^1.0.0",
"babel-core": "^6.3.26",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.10.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.7",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.14",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
"del": "^1.1.1",
"delorean": "^0.9.7",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"highcharts": "^5.0.0",
"immutable": "^3.7.6",
"jquery": "^2.1.4",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"moment": "^2.10.6",
"ng-quick-grid": "latest",
"ngmap": "^1.17.6",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"object-assign": "^1.0.0",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"react": "^0.14.5",
"react-addons-create-fragment": "^0.14.7",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.28.1",
"react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
"react-copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.4",
"react-datepicker": "^0.17.0",
"react-dom": "^0.14.5",
"react-paginate": "^0.5.4",
"react-redux": "^4.0.6",
"react-slick": "^0.9.3",
"redux": "^3.0.5",
"redux-batched-actions": "^0.1.1",
"redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
"sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"webpack": "^1.12.9",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.1.0",
"webpack-notifier": "^1.2.1"
```

Comment: On Windows by any chance? I've heard reports that it suffers *much* degraded performance compared to Yarn on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Yeah I am on windows. On a vm no less. Still i should expect a comparative improvement over npm yeh?

Comment: So it's a VM running Windows? If so, can you try: disabling your antivirus in the project folder and the Yarn cache folder and making sure you're using Yarn v0.18 or greater?

Comment: Ok i already had my source folder as an exclusion. i'll add the yarn cache folder (when i find it). running yarn v0.18. My original test i had the entire defender disabled so thats not going to impact my times.

Comment: So (commenters) you do see improvements in performance compared to npm, just not on windows?

Comment: On my Linux machine Yarn is definitely faster, but I don't have a Windows development machine to test, I just know that others have had problems with it.

Comment: I guess i have my answer then, thanks.